# dig succeeds, nslookup fails (with dnsmasq as the server)

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq, nslookup, dig, dns-lookup

I installed dnsmasq on a machine of mine (It's a Kubuntu 12.04 LTS), backed only by `/etc/hosts` (no connection to the Internet until later). Now, if I `dig mymachine`, I get 192.168.0.1, but if I try to `nslookup mymachine`, I get:

```
>> connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Tried also `nslookup mymachine.mynicedomain.org` - didn't work either. pinging (**Edit:**) succeeds. This happens *both* on the server machine itself and on other machines on the network.

How can I get the DNS lookups to work? What problem is preventing nslookup from succeeding?

### Additional Information

In the server's `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.0.1   mymachine
```

In the server's `nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts: files mdns4_mininal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

(admittedly, this is a bit weird; but I also tried:

```
hosts: files dns
```

instead, with the same effect)

In `resolv.conf` (which is generated by dnsmasq):

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search mynicedomain.org
```

In the server's `/etc/hosts.allow`:

```
domain: ALL
```

In the other machines' `/etc/resolv.conf` (this is set by the DHCP client):

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
search mynicedomain.org
```

Relevant netstat output on the server:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.1:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Finally, here's the `ipconfig` output from one of the client machines on the network (running Windows 7):

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mynicedomain.org
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 12-34-56-78-9A-BC
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.50(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, October 20th 2013 16:20:25
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, October 20th 2013 18:20:24
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

**Notes:**

- May be related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/95966/113898).

Comment: So far all you (appear) to know is that dnsmasq is listening and responding on the server's 127.0.0.1 intrface. Is dnsmasq listening on 192.168.0.1 (dig @192.168.0.1 ... | netstat ...)? Can the remote machines contact 192.168.0.1 at all (ping ssh etc )?

Comment: @Iain: Yes it is, and yes they can. Updated question accordingly.

Comment: Do you get any more hints as to what is happening if you do `set debug` in nslookup before the query?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist: This was over a year ago, I'm no longer experiencing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you configured your `/etc/resolv.conf`?
If not, it should be as follows:

```
search mynicedomain.org
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

When you use BIND or other DNS Servers, you should change `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file accordingly.

The following options are available:

- **dns**:  Use the Domain Name System (DNS) service to resolve the address. This makes sense only for host address resolution, not network address resolution. This mechanism uses the /etc/resolv.conf file.
- **files**:
  Search a local file for the host or network name and its corresponding address. This option uses the traditional /etc/hosts and /etc/network files.

Your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file should contain a like this, to enable DNS lookups.

```
hosts:       dns files
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was trying to drill it down step by step. As all the configuration seems correct. I guess the problem is here--> hosts: files mdns4_mininal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4 
Check the following [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27541/why-cant-my-machine-resolve-local-windows-hostnames)
You need to install 
    apt-get install winbind

Comment: okay deleted you can check the link in my last comment, if it works for you

Comment: Well, it turns out pinging actually _works_. I was running ping with a wrong setup before. The conundrum is still basically the same though.